# Code from XLSM doesn't work on other workbooks. How do I fix?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set up automatic processing of multiple files via an XLSM file with a macro button.  This macro button opens up all the other files in the folder and processes them.  The problem is that when the code opens other workbooks, the code seems to stop working on the other workbooks.

Even running this simple code on the workbooks I'm trying to process doesn't work:

```
Sub LR_Test()
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Print LR
End Sub
```

This errors out, saying "Application-defined or object-defined error", on:

```
LR = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

I did some debugging to make sure I have the correct activeworkbook and worksheet.  The workbooks being opened and processed by the code are xls files.  Most of them need to have editing enabled, but that is done with:

```
    If Not Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow Is Nothing Then
        Application.ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit
    End If
```

And I tested the active workbooks to make sure the editing is enabled at the time the code errors out.

When I open other workbooks with code in my personal.xlsb file, it can count lastrows and do any other function I write in, but I need other users to be able to use my code.  This is why I'm trying to make this code work from an XLSM file.

Any solution will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: "... opens up all the other files in the folder" - if you're using `Workbooks.Open`, it returns a `Workbook` reference that you most certainly should assign to a `Workbook` variable, rather than working against the `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: Thanks BigBen.  It's been a while since I posted here, but I remember getting some great answers from you in the past.  I was using a workbook variable, but simplified my sample code when posting here.  Turns out I had posted my code in the sheet object rather than a module.   So, the code was not being accessed or something when the other workbooks were opened.  Code is all working after inserting a module.  Noob mistake!

Comment: @BigBen, I trust you implicitly regarding code logic/rules.  This is why I've been using workbook variables ever since I first heard you say that.  However, I'm wondering if you wouldn't mind explaining why a workbook variable is preferred over `ActiveWorkbook`, and why a worksheet variable is preferred over `ActiveSheet`.  I've been using these methods without understanding why.

Comment: You can't necessarily guarantee that the `ActiveWorkbook` and `ActiveSheet` are what you think. Also, most of the time a workbook or sheet doesn't need to be active for you to do what you want.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks again.  You Sir are a gentleman and a scholar :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tinkering around for a bit, I realized I had put my code in one of the Microsoft Excel Objects (the sheet object in vba editor) rather than a module.  After creating a module in the XLSM file and pasting my code into the module, everything is working as intended.